# Overwrite / Extend the UploadFile.php class in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

With the following code I save the file with a unique name.
That's awesome, except I want it perfect.
I rather see the image with a name like: **path/to/file/name-of-the-file.jpg** and if there's a new one with the same name I like it to be: **path/to/file/name-of-the-file-2.jpg** instead of a unique "hash" in front.

`$path = $request->image->storeAs('themes', uniqid().'-'.$request->image->getClientOriginalName(), 'public');`

Is there a way to extend / overwrite the class "**UploadFile.php**" and add an extra method to this? So I can add method like: `storeAsUnique()`

I can see it's called within **/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php** on line 251 (in laravel 5.4).

I don't see how to extend this class.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, hashed filenames are the way to go. I recommend you using them, because they eliminate much of the overhead of dealing with files that have alphanumeric-ish names. That being said, if you still want to take your approach mentioned above, there are a few things you could do.

You could extend `UploadedFile` and implement the `storeAsUnique()` method. Inside such method you could do:

1) Scan the directory with [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) (or potentially [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) ) and allocate the results to a variable.

2) You will the compare each result to the name you want to give to the file you are about to create, say **file.jpeg**. If a match is found, then you will try to find **file2.jpeg**. If no match is found, you got it! Now suppose that in the second iteration, **file2.jpeg** is found. Then you will have to go on and try to find **file3.jpeg**.

The steps mentioned above, are fine for a small set of files. However, Imagine you have 100+ files that have a subsequent enumerated file, namely **file1.jpeg** to **file100.jpeg** then this operation will turn into a slow and resource expensive one, affecting the execution time of your script heavily. Of course that are many improvements that can be made to the 2-step recursive algorithm described above, but for many files, the outcome is generally the same.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: Hmm, the default method hashes the whole filename. That's bad in my opinion. Keeping original filenames is a big deal for SEO. I guess I stick wih the solution I have now. Part hash, part original name.

Comment: Of course you are not gonna expose the filename 38djqk38tkdmqi3o4mtnwok4mtd.jpeg to your user. That is why you have a table with an entry saying that such hash has a name of nice_name.jpeg. Filesystem and application filenames can be different, but you need to keep track of such things as you go.

Comment: But the actual filename the adress that points to the real image, has SEO value. No matter if you're showing it somewhere, use an alt tag or title tag. So I'm not sure how a table with entries keeping the real name can fix that. Suppose I the img src is nice_name.jpg, how would that point to {hashname}.jpg? Do I have to make a rewrite for all files checking if it is a image if so checking it against the database for the realname and return that image?

Comment: Suppose you have a table called files, with two columns `file_name` and `hash_name`. Whenever you upload a file, you use the regular method that hashes the name of your file by default, and you insert it in the column `hash_name`. But say you wanted that file to be named file3.jpeg. You just put that in the column `file_name`. Whenever you want to use the name of the file, just output it.That way, you keep your files organized. This solves some but not all problems of dealing with files, like heavy filesystem traversals when you look for a file. That is why Amazon's S3 buckets are real nice :)

Comment: AFAIK web crawlers check the name of your href attribute, not the name of the file itself. Then they might/might not analyze the bitmap of the image to determine its' content (especially nowadays with machine learning algorithms). So they would see a link to, say http://mypage.com/files/photo1.jpeg but you know that photo1.jpeg is  1) Unique, since its real name is hashed and it may be tied to a user. 2) It's real name (in the filesystem) is in a database and it is definitely not photo1.jpeg